# Updating the actual values upon filtering using PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using PrimeNG with Global filter added to my table:

```
 <input #gb type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Filter">
```

Datatable:

```
<p-dataTable *ngIf="users != null && users.length > 0" [value]="users" loadingIcon="fa-spinner" [globalFilter]="gb">
```

I need to send mails to the users that have been filtered. I noticed however that the users count (amount of users) does not update upon filter.

The records are displayed correctly based on the filter in the table but mailing these users would send the mail to all users retrieved from the DB.

Is there a way of updating the actual users' amount upon filter using PrimeNG filter option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DataTable` component has a variable called `filteredValue` and filtered values are stored in that variable. There are two ways to get filtered values:

> First way

You can use `ViewChild` to get a reference to `DataTable` object and get the users you filtered:

**Template**

```
<p-dataTable #dataTable *ngIf="users != null && users.length > 0" [value]="users" loadingIcon="fa-spinner" [globalFilter]="gb">
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTable } from 'primeng/primeng';

@ViewChild('dataTable')
dataTable: DataTable;
```

Now that you have reference to `DataTable` component, it is easy to get filtered users:

```
printFilteredUsers() {
  console.log(this.dataTable.filteredValue);
}
```

> Second way

`DataTable` component has event called `onFilter` which is triggered each time `DataTable`'s content is filtered:

**Template**

```
<p-dataTable *ngIf="users != null && users.length > 0"
  [value]="users" loadingIcon="fa-spinner" [globalFilter]="gb"
  (onFilter)="printFilteredUsers($event)">
```

**Component**

```
printFilteredUsers(event: any) {
  console.log(event.filteredValue); // filtered users
  console.log(event.filters); // applied filters
}
```

PrimeNG's `DataTable` is well documented, I suggest checking it out. You can do it [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable).